# Should we use encoding for HtmlString?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What's better in ASP.NET MVC

```
<%= Html.LabelForModel() %>
```

or

```
<%: Html.LabelForModel() %>
```

? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [view  template code tags - asp.net mvc - regd.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713578/view-template-code-tags-asp-net-mvc-regd)

Answer (score 5):

If it returns MvcHtmlString it won't matter; the `<%:` will know it is pre-escaped. I would therefore **use** `<%:` as then the reviewer doesn't need to think "is this escaped? or is this a raw field?".

Of course, that does depend on the code that *creates* the MvcHtmlString being sane...

Comment: it's not good argument. Why don't we write code like int count = 10; int price = 100; int cost = (int)price * (int)count;? It looks like <%= Html.Encode(Html.LabelForModel())%> or <%: Html.LabelForModel() %>.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't understand the comment, but if I see `<%:obj.LabelForModel()%>` I don't need to worry *at that layer* whether `LabelForModel` is meant to return HTML or an unescaped string. With `<%=obj.LabelForModel%>` I very much **do** need to know. That is the point I am trying to make.

Comment: I've tried to say that if you worry about encoding non-escaped strings it's not good way to try encode everything.

Comment: @Dmitry you **should** worry about encoding non-encoded strings, and that *doesn't* try to encode everything. A second time, I simply don't understand the comment.

Comment: I completely agree that we should encode usual string to exclude XSS. But when I see using encode method for required html murk up... it's very Microsoft style to make methods named Encode that don't encode in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is "better". They both output the same exact markup.

Comment: When two methods do a same which one should we use? First or second? Or from time to time first and from time to time second? ))